# Is it possible to call a function at the time of deployment if it is not in constructor?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, uniswap, constructor

This code is from [UniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol)

```
constructor() public {
        factory = msg.sender;
    }

    // called once by the factory at time of deployment
    function initialize(address _token0, address _token1) external {
        require(msg.sender == factory, 'UniswapV2: FORBIDDEN'); // sufficient check
        token0 = _token0;
        token1 = _token1;
    }
```

It says for "initialize" function "called once by the factory at the time of deployment". Is it even possible to deploy and call a function at the same time or address who deployed the contract will manually call the "initalize" function right after contract deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

It's actually a known security issue because a smart contract calling a function in the constructor ends up having a codesize = 0 during said call.

Some contracts check that the caller has a codesize = 0 to be sure the caller is an externally owned account (EOA), and a smart contract calling in the constructor (i.e. deployment time) has a codesize of 0 and looks like an EOA.

There is one or two ethernaut capture the flag about this very fact.

For the initialize, there is an openzeppelin library about constructor initialize. Check it [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades/blob/master/packages/core/contracts/Initializable.sol)

Hope this helps!